# How to migrate Umbraco CMS Members with passwords from Umbraco v8 instance to another Umbraco v10

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, umbraco8, umbraco-10

Good day to all of you reading this message and thanks in advance for your time.

I am updating my Umbraco 8 site to Umbraco 10 and also from .NET Framework 4.x.x to .NET Core 6.0.

Everything is going well, except the CMS Members migration, especifically passwords. I am using uSync.Complete to migrate the members from one instance to another and according to uSync I have to install the same Machinekey in all Umbraco instances for the passwords to be migrated as well, yet in .net core we use the DataProtection.

The machine key I have inside the web.config file has a decryptionkey, validationkey, validation and decryption properties too and in .NET Core it uses a masterKey. I have been struggling for a couple of days trying to use all sorts of libraries and packages like AspNetTicketBridge https://github.com/dmarlow/AspNetTicketBridge/blob/master/README.md to achieve this machinekey migration.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var validationKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var decryptionKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var decryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
        var validationAlgorithm = "HMACSHA256";

    var machineKeyProvider = new MachineKeyDataProtector(validationKey, decryptionKey,decryptionAlgorithm, validationAlgorithm);

    services.AddSingleton(machineKeyProvider);

    var keysFolder = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Shared/Keys");
    services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("my-app-name")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysFolder));
   
    // other services configured under.

    }
```

How can I use the AspNetTicketBridge in this specific scenario or if you know any other way that achieves the same result, could you please enlighten me?

The end goal is migrating the CMS Member passwords from Umbraco v8 to v10. So if we can skip this whole machine key process and we can migrate the passwords then I will also be satisfied with this answer.

I almost never post anything here so if I am being unclear please forgive me and ask me any follow up question you need.

Kind Regards,
Yaacob

I have tried using the AspNetTicketBridge without luck so far on my specific scenario.

The end goal is migrating the CMS Member passwords from Umbraco v8 to v10. So if we can skip this whole machine key process and we can migrate the passwords then I will also be satisfied with this answer.